# GCE metadata and terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am using terraform to automate GCE creation. I want to automate user creation. Furthermore, I am trying to use metadata to auto create users. But it doesn't work.

```
metadata = {
    windows-startup-script-cmd    = "net user /add ${var.windows_user} ${random_string.random.result} /Y"
}
```

In gcp console it looks like this: [gcp console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqWAd.png)

Some has similar problem?

Comment: 1) `but it doesn't work` is not helpful. What does not work and what are the errors? 2) RDP into the Windows instance and test the startup script with this command: `C:\Program Files\Google\Compute Engine\metadata_scripts\run_startup_scripts.cmd`

Comment: No errors and when I run script from this path, it works :)

Comment: Did you verify that the user is created correctly?

Comment: Enable the serial port `serial-port-logging-enable = "TRUE"` in the metadata, repeat the deployment and then review the output from this command: `gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output <INSTANCE_NAME> --zone <REGION>` 
There will be a section in the serial port output for the startup script processing. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_instance_serial_port